# How to access an array property from a class wrapped inside observable in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, rxjs-observables, angular15

I am trying to populate a dropdown by accessing an array property from the class which is wrapped inside an observable.

I have an interface like below :

```
export interface IApplicationConfigurationResponse
{
   settings?: Settings[] ] undefined;
}

export class ApplicationConfigurationResponse
{
   settings?: Settings[] ] undefined;
}

export class Settings 
{
   settingId!:number;
   name!:string;
}
```

**state-management.service.ts:**

```
@Injectable
export class StateManagementService
{
    private subjectConfigurations =  new BehaviourSubject<ApplicationConfigurationResponse>(null);
    
    getApplicationConfigurations(){
       return this.subjectSettings.asObservable().pipe(filter(k) => k!=null);
    }
    
    set saveApplicationConfiguration(state: ApplicationConfigurationResponse)
    {
        this.subjectConfigurations.next(state);
    }
}
```

**master.component.ts:**

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-master',
..
..
})

export class MasterComponent implements OnInit
{
    constructor(private myService: MyService,
                private stateService: StateManagementService) {}
                
                
    ngOnInit():void {
    this.myService.getApplicationConfigurationsFromBackend().subscribe((res) ==> {
       this.stateService.saveApplicationConfiguration = res;
    }
}
```

**header.component.ts:**

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-header',
..
..
})

export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit
{
    applicationConfigurationResponse$ : Observable<ApplicationConfigurationResponse>();
    constructor(private stateService: StateManagementService) {}
                        
    ngOnInit():void {
       this.applicationConfigurationResponse$ = this.stateService.getApplicationConfigurations;
    }
}
```

**header.component.html:**

```
<div>
       <select class="dropdown">
            <option *ngFor="let setting of applicationConfigurationResponse$.settings | async" [value] = "setting.settingId">
                  {{ setting.name }}
             </option>
       </select>  
</div>
```

But I am getting error on below line:

[image]

I am not able to access the property which is wrapped inside an observable.

How can I access the `Settings[]` from `ApplicationConfigurationResponse` and populate a dropdown?

Comment: Is this just a typo while writing the question? `this.stateService.getApplicationConfigurations` (missing parenthesis at the end of the method)

Comment: You probably want to do: `let settings of (applicationConfigurationResponse$ | async)?.settings` and then, `{{settings?.name}}`

Comment: please share error message

Comment: @julianobrasil Thank you so much. This worked but is there a way to preselect a value in dropdown which is not the first one?

Comment: @NagaSaiA It just show red squigly error line. Dont show exact error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access the observable, subscribe to it, then use the settings property using Async Pipe, or you can do something like this

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
applicationConfigurationResponse$ : 
Observable<ApplicationConfigurationResponse>();
constructor(private stateService: StateManagementService) {}
                    
ngOnInit():void {
   this.applicationConfigurationResponse$ = 
   this.stateService.getApplicationConfigurations;
}
get settings() {
  return this.applicationConfigurationResponse$.pipe(map(res => res.settings));
}
}
```

and in html

```
<div>
   <select class="dropdown">
        <option *ngFor="let setting of settings | async" [value]="setting.settingId">
              {{ setting.name }}
         </option>
   </select>  
</div>
```

Comment: Upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me. Is there any way to preselect any different value in dropdown apart from the first value in the settings array?

Comment: yes, in this case, you need to set value attribute of select element at the start, or you can set selected at option if you know which one should be selected